# batch matrix inner product of a row with every other row in matrix, in PyTorch

Tags: python, math, pytorch

I have two matrices A of sizes (16, 8, 400) , B of size(16, 50, 400) ; where 16 is the batch size.

Now what I need to do is this:

For every batch in A, I want to compute the inner product of each row in a single batch of A with each row in a single batch of B and then get the max inner product value. In other words, for every batch, I have a (8, 400) matrix on left-hand side (A) and a (50, 400) matrix on right-hand side (B). Now for each row (8 * 400) in A, I want to compute inner product of that row with each of the (1 * 400) rows in B, one by one, and get the max inner product. The inner product operation would thus result in a (8 * 1) sized vector, and then get the max value of the 8 values. Done for each batch it would result in (16, 50, 1) sized matrix, which is the preferred dimension of my output.

The mathematical formula is shown in the figure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZoAV.png)

How do I go about doing this? I do not want to use for loops, since that would be inefficient. I also do not want to use repeat method for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
C = np.max( np.matmul(A, B.transpose(0,2,1)) , axis=1 )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I verified it with a random matrix and there is no problem with the dimension of the output. I will verify the correctness of the value afterwards